# How does one manipulate Unicode strings at the character level?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Sometimes manipulating character strings at the character level is unavoidable.

Here I have a function written for ANSI/ASCII based character strings that replaces CR/LF sequences with LF only, and also replaces CR with LF.  We use this because incoming text files often have goofy line endings due to various text or email programs that have made a mess of them, and I need them to be in a consistent format to make parsing / processing / output work properly down the road.

Here's a fairly efficient implementation of this compression from various line-endings to LF only, for single byte per character implementations:

```
// returns the in-place conversion of a Mac or PC style string to a Unix style string (i.e. no CR/LF or CR only, but rather LF only)
char * AnsiToUnix(char * pszAnsi, size_t cchBuffer)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; pszAnsi[i]; ++i, ++j)
    {
        // bounds checking
        ASSERT(i < cchBuffer);
        ASSERT(j <= i);

        switch (pszAnsi[i])
        {
            case '\n':
                if (pszAnsi[i + 1] == '\r')
                    ++i;
                break;

            case '\r':
                if (pszAnsi[i + 1] == '\n')
                    ++i;
                pszAnsi[j] = '\n';
                break;

            default:
                if (j != i)
                    pszAnsi[j] = pszAnsi[i];
        }

    }

    // append null terminator if we changed the length of the string buffer
    if (j != i)
        pszAnsi[j] = '\0';

    // bounds checking
    ASSERT(pszAnsi[j] == 0);

    return pszAnsi;
}
```

I'm trying to transform this into something that will work correctly with multibyte/unicode strings, where the size of the next character can be multible bytes wide.

So:

1. I need to look at a character only at a valid character-point (not in the middle of a character)
2. I need to copy over the portion of the character that is part of the rejected piece properly (i.e. copy whole characters, not just bytes)

I understand that _mbsinc() will give me the address of the next start of a real character.  But what is the equivalent for Unicode (UTF16), and are there already primitives to be able to copy a full character (e.g. length_character(wsz))?

Comment: If that is what you mean I suggest replacing occurrences of 'character' with the Unicode terminology of 'code point', to be unambiguous.

Comment: in UTF16, `\r` and `\n` are always a single `wchar_t` (with the same values as ASCII and UTF8!) so copying them is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the beautiful things about UTF-8 is that if you only care about the ASCII subset, your code doesn't need to change at all. The non-ASCII characters get encoded to multi-byte sequences where all of the bytes have the upper bit set, keeping them out of the ASCII range themselves. Your CR/LF replacement should work without modification.

UTF-16 has the same property. Characters that can be encoded as a single 16-bit entity will *never* conflict with the characters that require multiple entities.

Comment: And UTF-16 has the same property when taken 16 bits at a time instead of 8 bits at a time.

Comment: @SteveJessop, very true, but of course with UTF-16 the situation comes up much less often.

Comment: Sure, I mention it only because the questioner asked about it ("what is the equivalent for Unicode (UTF16)").

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't only care about the ASCII subset.  I can have strings which come from a file from Japan, which contains messed up line endings as well as Kanjii (encoded as UTF16 at the point where I'm processing it with this function).  I can't very well be looking at a wchar_t that is actually the second part of a single glyph to see if it is equal to L'\n' or L'\r'!

Comment: @Mordachai, that's my point - the latter parts of a multi-part sequence will *never* match `L'\n'` or `L'\r'`.

Comment: Okay - that's huge!  Excellent.  But what if I did need to look at characters and do manipulation where what' I'm looking for cannot be guaranteed not to be part of a second-character within a code-point?

Comment: @Mordachai: it is always possible to look at a single 16-bit code unit in UTF-16 data, and determine which of the following three holds: (1) it represents a unicode code point, (2) it is the first code unit of two that together represent a code point, (3) it is the second code unit of two that together represent a code point. The range `0xD800 - 0xDBFF` is reserved for (2), and `0xDC00 - 0xDFFF` for (3). You can manufacture odd cases with badly-coded data masquerading as UTF-16, but other than that the issue shouldn't arise.

Comment: But to answer your what-if, I'm actually not sure whether Windows does provide the function you're looking for (to get the length in code units or bytes of a code point representation in UTF-16 data). For most purposes Windows treats UTF-16 as though it were a fixed-width encoding, because UTF-16 was deliberately designed so that you can. If it doesn't provide the function then you can either do the same, or very easily implement it yourself.

Comment: What I'm hearing, if I understand you correctly, is that I can for most purposes simply ignore the "how many wchar_t are in this code-point" and just look at the character.  lead bytes will match, trailing bytes (or surrogate pairs, or ternary sequences) simply won't match the comparison (assuming I'm not searching for a character which itself requires multiple storage-units to express).

Comment: @Mordachai, if by "lead bytes" you mean instead "single bytes" then you're correct. I would usually interpret "lead" to be the first part of a multi-part sequence, and they occupy their own unique space in the encoding and won't match anything else.

Comment: Okay - now I'm reading the UTF-8 everywhere link you posted, and damned if that doesn't sound like the better approach.  Sigh... not gonna happen anytime soon - too much work to convert a second time - and restrictions on external files always being UTF-8 is problematical.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to keep text internally in mix of whatever encodings and work with those it is true Hell.

First pick some "internal" encoding. When target platform is UNIX then UTF-8 is good candidate, it is slightly easier to display there. When target platform is Windows then UTF-16 is good candidate, Windows uses it internally anyway everywhere. Whatever you pick, stick to it an only it.

Then you convert all incoming "dirty" text into that encoding. Also you may make some re-formatting that actually looks exactly like your code, only that on case of wchar_t containing UTF-16 you have to use literals like `L'\n'`.

Comment: "When target platform is Windows then UTF-16 is good candidate" - and so is UTF-8, if http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ is credible.

Comment: That's what I'm working towards.  Unfortunately, incoming files are sometimes either produced or edited in external programs.  Email is notorious for scrambling line ends, but they're not the only ones.  At the end of the day, I need to know that I have a clean data stream to process at the back-end, which is in UTF-16 at that point, with normalized lineendings.

Comment: @Steve Jessop they suggest constant widen(utf8).c_str() calls when working with OS API. Such needless string processing results with noticeable performance overhead (by my experience 2-3 times slower). When 2-3 times slower is fine for them then they should really write C# or VisBasic.NET.

Comment: That depends on which OS API, of course, and how you rig your benchmarks. When opening a file, it doesn't take twice as long to transcode the filename as it does to read the file, so a real program will not experience a 3x slowdown. If all your program does is call `wcslen` then sure, transcoding is a considerable expense.

Comment: Also, files are much more likely to be encoded in UTF-8 than UTF-16.

Comment: On re-read that was dismissive, sorry. If your program *mostly uses OS APIs to process text*, then the performance of converting the strings matters because you're doing it a lot. My experience of using UTF8 internally on a wide-character system, (admittedly on Symbian rather than Windows, but it was the same deal with converting to use OS APIs) was that the overhead was negligible. That's because the OS APIs we used that did things with strings were all slow operations already (for example rendering text) compared with the pass over the data to convert it.

Comment: Texts are used a lot in various Windows API's, not only GUI and file names. See windows API has at least 30K BSTR parameters in it. My experience was related to database. MS databases are good, but you can severely slow that down if you do a lot of needless text conversions back and forth.

Comment: @ÖöTiib For any database I know, including MS, there is a way to create a simple byte string as a field, so you can send UTF-8 strings into it. Regardless of that - is conversion really a performance problem for you when communicating with a database?

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: if you want to interoperate with an existing database, that might have for example collation rules on the field already defined on the DB side, then you can't just replace all the wide text in the DB with UTF8. If you're creating a new DB then I honestly don't know all the consequences of using `varbinary` instead of text fields, but it must limit what the DB can do for you. As you imply, I think this would be a case for profiling. Often it won't matter because in practice converting wide text to/from UTF-8 is slower than copying it, but not orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: @Pavel: Btw, if you can add thorough advice on using UTF-8 fields in SQL Server to the utf8everywhere manifesto, that would be ace :-) But I suspect it might be a bit beyond the scope of the manifesto to contain specific info on how to use every tool out there.

Comment: @Steve Jessop The reason of differences of our experiences may be that the texts I had were not of Latin alphabet. I can usually redesign the software that my team write. The interfaces with external parts have to usually stay what they are. There are plenty of situations when usage of UTF-16 is optimal, I trust most cases on Windows are such.

Comment: @SteveJessop Perhaps you propose a wording, and we edit and merge?

Comment: @oo the more I work, the more I realize there is likely no such case. The FAQ section of utf8everywhere.org addresses every possible claim we encountered, including that of a latin alphabet.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: ah, no, the reason I ask for its inclusion is because I *haven't* done this. I use nvarchar in the one SQL Server database I interact with (I've used UTF-8 in sqlite). But if someone has assessed the pros and cons of UTF-8 in SQL Server databases then I'd certainly consider it. It may be that SQL Server can be considered in effect an external transport medium whose "natural" encoding is non-UTF-8, or it may be that the features it offers for nvarchar can relatively easily be reproduced for UTF-8 fields. I just don't know.

Comment: @PavelRadzilovsky what your website suggests about modules using MS COM interfaces? All of these use BSTR. What it claims about interfacing with processes written in Java or C#? Both those languages use UTF-16. During pointless conversion you have both copies so on ultimate cases it will peak on double memory usage if to compare with one or other. You can always say that my measured performance differences were measured somehow wrongly, but that certainly was not the case. Sure when writing to file I can convert to UTF-8 and maybe even compress too, hard drives are still so slow.

Comment: OO, COM interfaces are a valid point. Are there high-performance COM communications that you have in mind? Storing UTF-16 in preparation for BSTR conversion would be considered an optimization then. C# and Java - before saying it is their problem, I'd suggest performance-demanding text processing applications in these languages (communications-to-disk-etc) to use byte arrays.

Comment: Pavel, COM is well performing, C++ language binding is great and so it has to be considered as factor if you want to clean the universe from UTF-16. Other thing you should think about is QT. It is very popular framework and internally, QString stores its value using the UTF-16 encoding. When there are serious QT fans in team then I always consider keeping texts in other modules as UTF-16 as well. Just to have less conversions.

Comment: well, for Qt the frequency argument holds. Qt is a UI framework.. Also, the internal string representation may change. I wish they'd just use the std::string though. I started doing some research on DBMS. Conclusions will be posted.

Comment: In my experience, the fact that UTF-8 is the "standard encoding of the Internet" overshadows Windows' UTF-16 preference.  YMMV.

Comment: @Pavel QT is not just widget toolkit it is application framework. I know several QT-heavy programs with no GUI at all. Qt. Popularity: ~10% of C++ questions here are about QT.